# Checking a passed in date is between two separate columns

Tags: mysql, between

I am trying to use todays date with `cur_date()` and trying to pull all the columns where it is between a `datestart` column and a `dateend` column.

I have tried both the below queries but get: *Unknown column 'tdate' in 'where clause'*

```
SELECT id, 
       details, 
       CURDATE() AS tdate 
FROM specials 
WHERE tdate BETWEEN datestart AND dateend;

SELECT id, 
       details, 
       CURDATE() AS tdate 
FROM specials WHERE datestart <= tdate AND dateend >= tdate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field alias is not seen in WHERE clause, try this query instead -

```
SELECT
  id, details, CURDATE() AS tdate FROM specials
WHERE
  datestart <= CURDATE() AND dateend >= CURDATE();
```

Or use a subquery -

```
SELECT id, details, tdate FROM (
  SELECT id, details, CURDATE() AS tdate FROM specials
    ) t
WHERE
  datestart <= tdate AND dateend >= tdate;
```